# Passing information from Razor client (cshtml) to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following razor file:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Blah";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.InitModule = "myFooModule";
}

@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/recipes.js"></script>
}
<div data-ng-view
```

Here is my angularjs code:

```
var testModule = angular.module("myFooModule", ['ngRoute']);

appetizerModule.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        controller: "myController",
        templateUrl: "/Templates/test.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
}]);
```

I would like to pass a variable with data like "myuserinfofromPage" from my razor page to my angularJs so that I can use that data ("myuserinfofromPage") to perform certain set of operations. I am struggling to get a clean way to pass data as I am new to AngularJS. What's the best way to pass simple data from Razor(cshtml) to my Angular code?

Comment: In angular you normally get data from an asynchronous web API call that is a different request than your main web page.  I suggest you set up a Web API controller.

Comment: I did! But I would like to pass a parameter from my razor view to my Angular code. I am calling my Web API in my angular controller and want to reuse the same code for different views. Sorry if it sounded more complex than what it is.

Comment: in future consider using ng-init to initialize scope variables from markup

Comment: in future consider giving a code example

Answer (score 11):

You could embed the following in your razor page:

```
 <script>
  app.value('myValue', @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))
 <script>
```

Where Model is a .NET object you want to render.

Then inject it into your controller:

```
 app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, myValue) 
 {
      //use myValue
 });
```

Comment: Does it matter if it is _Layout or View?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data in json format to you view and after bootstrap your data using factory ie:

```
testModule.factory('UserService', function () {

      var _userInfo= @Html.Raw(ViewBag.UserDataInJsonFormat); //<- your data is going here

      return {
      userInfo : _userInfo

      }
```

}

Comment: Thanks pixelbits and sylwester for your responses. I have used angular directives to pass the element data and stored it in $scope variable in my angular controllers. Reference: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/directives/passing-configuration-params-using-html-attributes.html

Comment: @sylwester I am getting `Unexpected token @ in JSON at position 0`.   Is there anything additional needed?

Comment: @stevek it looks like you have got not valid json

Answer (score 0):

Thanks pixelbits and sylwester for your responses. I have used angular directives to pass the element data and stored it in $scope variable in my angular controllers. Reference: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/directives/passing-configuration-params-using-html-attributes.html

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div my-widget="Hello World"></div>
</body>
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.directive("myWidget", function() {
  var linkFunction = function(scope, element, attributes) {
    scope.text = attributes["myWidget"];
  };

  return {
    restrict: "A",
    template: "<p></p>",
    link: linkFunction
  };
});
```